# How to use treeview with angular ui grid

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Ho guys, i'm using angular ui grid in my project..heres my code :

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        exporterMenuCsv: false,
       // enableGridMenu: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        enableSorting: true,

         onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi; //set gridApi on scope
             gridApi.core.on.renderingComplete($scope, function () {
              $timeout(function () {
                var gridBodyElem = document.getElementById(gridApi.grid.id + '-grid-container');
                gridBodyElem.addEventListener('mouseup', handleGridClick);
              });
            });
      },

columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name',displayName:'Name',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'uniqueid',displayName:'ID',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'devicetime',displayName:'GPS DATE',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'adress',displayName:'Adresse',cellClass: 'gridField'},
      { field: 'company',displayName:'Company',cellClass: 'gridField'}
]
```

};

it works good but i want to use a treeview in this grid to obtain like this table grid below..
[image]

what i want exacly is, when i click on item, i want to show a html code below like the image above...is there anyone has any idea how to do this..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example controller :

```
var SomeController = function () {

    this.customHtml = '<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>';
}
```

Example view :

```
<div ng:bind="customHtml"></div>
```

Gives :

```
<div>
    "<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>"
</div>
```

Comment: but how can impliment it in the ui grid??

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid  Please visit this link  that you will get more idea.